# How can I source this shell script before starting a rinari console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, emacs, rinari

In my project, we have a shell script that sets default values for some environment variables. When I try to run `rinari-console`, I receive an error because the script has not been sourced. Is there a way to make sure rinari sources it, so that when the rails console starts, all the variables have the needed values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright I've been thinkg a bit harder about the question. I've come up with two possible solutions:

## Outside Emacs via wrapper

This solution is a bit clumsy, but it should work.

You could create a wrapper script, e.g. 'emacs-wrapper.sh':

```
#!/bin/sh
set -a
. YOUR-SCRIPT.sh
emacs
```

If you launch ./emacs-wrapper.sh, YOUR-SCRIPT.sh will be sourced and Emacs is started after that. The same environment will be visible to Emacs this way. Testing this approach on my machine, I was able to *(getenv "var")* all variables defined in YOUR-SCRIPT.sh

## Nicer: Within Emcas via shell-command

This is IMO a much nicer solution since it runs completely inside Emacs. Makes a call to shell-command-to-string to source your YOUR-SCRIPT.sh. At the end it also dumps that process' environment. This is subsequently added to Emacs' own process-environment:

```
;; defadvice is optional, you could also just call source-script directly
(defadvice rinari-console (before init-environment activate)
   (source-script "/PATH/TO/YOUR-SCRIPT.sh"))

(defun source-script (script)
   (let ((env (extract-environment script)))
       (mapc 'import-environment-variable (split-string env "\n"))))

(defun extract-environment (script)
   (shell-command-to-string (format "set -a; . %s > /dev/null 2>&1; env" script)))

(defun import-environment-variable (variable-assignment)
   (when (not (or (null variable-assignment) (string= "" variable-assignment)))
      (let* ((key-value-pair (split-string variable-assignment "="))
             (key (car key-value-pair))
             (value (cadr key-value-pair)))
        (setenv key value))))
```

I verified this approach on my machine as well. All variables defined in YOUR-SCRIPT were also defined in Emacs.

Comment: Your approach is great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do what you wanted with a wrapper.
Suppose you create a rails project in `~/test`.
Rinari will try to launch `irb` by executing the command `~/test/script/console`.
I created a wrapper named `~/test/script/console.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

. ~/test/script/env.sh
~/test/script/console
```

The wrapper sources your script containing the environment variables and then executes the regular command.

The file `~/test/script/env.sh` contains:

```
export TEST=test
```

Now to use that wrapper, call `rinari-mode` with a prefix argument `C-u M-x rinari-mode` and add a `.sh` to the end of the proposed command. The environment variable `TEST` will be set.

You could then create a macro that adds the `.sh` automatically.

Comment: For some reason, this solution causes my Ubuntu to freeze :)

Comment: With the example I gave or with your script. If it is with your script please copy it somewhere to see what is going on.

Answer (score -1):

I don't use rinari so there could be better ways to do it, but in principle you can do this to run "YOUR-SCRIPT.sh" before running actual rinari-console command.

```
(defadvice rinari-console (before run-my-script activate)
  (shell-command "YOUR-SCRIPT.sh"))
```

See also: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html

Comment: I've tried your answer, but it does not source the `YOUR_SCRIPT.sh`, so when the rinari console starts, it does not have those values.

Comment: Ah, you want to source the script, not run it.  I didn't notice you mentioned it in the question.  Probably it's better to change the title then?

Comment: I've changed it, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, but what the difference between source script and run script?

Comment: When you source a shell script (`source SCRIPT.sh`), the caller script shares namespace with callee script.  On the other hand, when you run it (`bash SCRIPT.sh`), variables defined in the callee script SCRIPT.sh are not introduced to the caller script.

Comment: It's not a clean way, but you can start Emacs using a script containing `source YOUR-SCRIPT.sh; emacs`, provided that environment variables set in YOUR-SCRIPT.sh are exported.  (or even type the line in terminal to start Emacs)

Answer (score -1):

Well if you wanna source the script, should you be able to do something very similar to what tkf suggested:

```
(defadvice rinari-console (before run-my-script activate)
  (shell-command ". YOUR-SCRIPT.sh"))
```

Comment: This fails to address the fundamental problem.  The shell command runs in a different process than the Rinari console.